# How to get the via field in twitter using Twitter4j?

Tags: java, android, twitter4j

I am working on Twitter integration with android using Twitter4j library. I have user access token and secrets and i am also able to get username and his/her tweets below is the code for this.

```
AccessToken a = new AccessToken(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
        // twitter.updateStatus(msg);

        List<Status> statuses = twitter.getFriendsTimeline();
        System.out.println("Showing friends timeline.");
        for (Status status : statuses) {
             System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":"
             + status.getText() + ":" + status.);

        }
```

Now I want to fetch the **Via field message** which comes in some tweets but not able to do this please help me to do this I have also attached the screen shot what I want to fetch please look into this and give me any suggestion on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Who retweeted the status shows up a little bit differently on the Twitter home page now.

[image: Retweet]

When I fetch and print the above status in Java using:

```
System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":" + status.getText());
```

I get the following result:

> Stack Exchange:RT @StackGameDev: Should Vector3 inherit from Vector2? http://t.co/JZXXB6kr #architecture

So, the `User` who retweeted the status can be read directly using the `status.getUser()` method.

The user who originally posted the tweet is a little bit trickier to get.  There is no method (that I could find) to directly read the original poster, but you can see from the example above that Twitter prepends the user's name to the text of the message ("RT @StackGameDev: " in the example).